# Disable lazy loading doctrine zend framework?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How can I disable lazy loading in doctrine 2?

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\StudentClass');
$result = $repo->findBy(array('pkStudentClass' => '1' ));

print_r($result);
```

I'm getting here too many data and the script fails.

Comment: You will always get objects back from doctrine. `$result` will be a `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` (which takes care of the lazy loading). Use `$result->toArray()` to return an `array` of all the `Application\Entity\StudentClass` entities within the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following query for the data retrieve
You can retrieve here needed column and retrieve needed records.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('U.id,U.name')  
                    ->from('Application\Entity\StudentClass', 'U')
                    ->where('U.pkStudentClass = :pkStudentClass')
                    ->setParameter('pkStudentClass', 1)
                    ->setMaxResults(20); 
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC') 
                    ->getQuery();
```

$result = $query->getScalarResult();

Comment: i know but sometimes we need to retrieve the whole object.